# PageViewController with the same ViewController and different ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to know is it possible to make PageViewController where two types of ViewController would be used. But one of them would have several pages.

So far, I have googled just two realizations, either one ViewController with multiple pages is used in PageViewController or multiple single paged ViewControllers are used in PageViewController.

Comment: You can return any `UIViewController`subclass for your pages. They can be multiple instances of the one view controller or different view controllers or any mix

Comment: What does a "view controller with several pages" mean? Does it have a scroll view or something?

Comment: @Paulw11 I mean it should be one instance of one VC and one instance of the other VC. But one of the VCs is paged multiple times

Comment: @EmilioPelaez It means one instance of VC but it can be paged, it doesn't have scroll view

Comment: You one instance of a view controller per page.  If you had 4 pages and you wanted three to be vc1 and one to be vc2 then you have three instances of vc1 and one of vc2. You can't use the same instance on multiple pages.